# How recompile ionic plugin after some customization

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have edited the plugin in ionic and removed platform and again added platform android to the app. However my changes were not applied.

Plugin : cordova-lugin-media-capture

added two features in the end

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7){
                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", req.duration);
                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.videoQuality", req.quality);
                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture", true); //added
                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT); //added
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try copying the modified file directly to the platform src directory:

```
cp plugins/cordova-plugins-media-capture/src/android/Capture.java platforms/android/src/org/apache/codova/media-capture/
```

and build the project again.

I would also suggest you to put several Log.d() before and after your changes, to be sure that the changes have taken effect.

```
Log.d("MODIFIED", "BEFORE platform check");
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7){
    Log.d("MODIFIED", "IN platform check");
    (...)
}
Log.d("MODIFIED", "AFTER platform check");
```

Also bear in mind, that the constant [android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) is only available in API level >= 9

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be direct edit on the folder platforms/android/src/[plugin folder]/[plugin filename] which will recompile when you build your app. After testing passed, you can apply the changes to the local plugin folder or wherever applicable.